# How to use the black/white image as the input to tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

When implementing the reinforcement learning with tensorflow, the inputs are black/white images. Each pixel can be represented as a bit 1/0.

Can I give the data directly to tensorflow, with each bit as a feature? Or I had to expand the bits to bytes before sending to tensorflow? I'm new to tensorflow, so some code example would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. you can define boolean as the input data type

Comment: Does that mean I still need to transform the raw image data to a boolean array somehow? Would that use much more memories? Thanks

Comment: It might use more memory at the "interface" point. but when it transformed into a tensor form, tensorflow will take care of internal representation according to a data type defined on that tensor.

Comment: To elaborate more, once it's inside of Tensorflow(GPU), it will reduce the size of boolean representation by compress into a byte. ref: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/d93a55b8592656bd73f4872ceaa6951e6565f841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly load the Image data as you would normally do, the Image being binary will have no effect other that the input channel width becoming 1 for the input.

Whenever you put an Image through a convnet, each output filter generally learns features for all the channels, so in case of a binary image, there is a separate kernel defined for each input channel / output channel combination (Since Only 1 input channel) in the first layer.

Each channel is defined by it's `number of filters` and there exists a 2D kernel for each input channel which averages over all filters, so you will have weights/parameters equal to `input_channels * number_of_filters * filter_dims`, here for the first layer `input_channels` becomes one.

Since you asked for some sample code.
Let your image be in a tensor X, simply use

`X_out = tf.nn.conv2d(X, filters = 6, kernel_size = [height,width])`

After that you can apply an activation, this will make your output image have 6 channels. If you face any problem or have some doubts, feel free to comment, for theoretical clarification, check out https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/lecture/nsiuW/one-layer-of-a-convolutional-network

**Edit**

Since the question was about simple neural net, not conv net, here is the code for that,

`X_train` is the variable in which image is stored as (n_x,n_x) byte resolution, n_x is used later.

You will need to flatten the input.

`X_train_flatten = X_train_orig.reshape(X_train_orig.shape[0], -1).T` 
This first flattens the image horizontally and then transposes it to arrange it vertically.

Then you will create placeholder tensor `X` as :

`X = tf.placeholder(tf.bool,[n_x*n_x,None])`  #Your Input tensor should have dimension same as your input layer.

let `W, b` be weight and bias respectively.

```
Z1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W1,X),b1)  #Linear Transformation step
A1 = tf.nn.relu(Z1)              #Activation Step
```

And you keep on creating your graph, I think that answers your question, if not let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have some doubt on the code. With this code, would tensorflow consider the input as a grayscale image instead of a binary image? I didn't see anything to tell tensorflow consider each bit as a feature. Have I miss anything. Thanks

Comment: Oh, so you are not using Convnet but rather a simple neural net, ok let me update

Comment: Edited accordingly. Follow the section after the edit.